# How to send SENDGRID email with html contents from Nodejs?

Tags: node.js, sendgrid

I have designed a template from Sendgrid website. Let's call it `sendgrid.html`

I am trying to send the email from `Nodejs` with the design from `sendgrid.html`. Below is my Nodejs code:

```
function sendVoucherCodeEmail (emailAddress, voucherCode){
    sgMail.setApiKey(process.env.SENDGRID_API_KEY);
    const msg = {
        to: emailAddress,
        from: 'example@example.com',
        subject: 'YourCode',
        text: ''
    };
}
```

I would like to pass `emailAddress` and `voucherCode` into the html content and send it as email to the user. How can I do it ? Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 6):

It's better to create a template on sendgrid and just put the ID of the template when sending using sendgrid API. By doing this, you can easy change the content without deploy new app. You can still inject the needed data into the template.

```
const sgMail = require('@sendgrid/mail');
sgMail.setApiKey(process.env.SENDGRID_API_KEY);
sgMail.setSubstitutionWrappers('{{', '}}');
const msg = {
  to: emailAddress,
  from: 'example@example.com',
  templateId: templateId,
  dynamic_template_data: {emailAddress, voucherCode},
};
```

!note: sendgrid change their API. So `substitutions` in V2 is replaced by `dynamic_template_data` in V3: https://github.com/sendgrid/sendgrid-nodejs/issues/703

To know how to create template, you can visit the official document here: https://sendgrid.com/docs/User_Guide/Transactional_Templates/create_and_edit_transactional_templates.html

Your placeholder in your template should be surrounded by `{{` `}}`. for example:  `{{emailAddress}}`

Comment: emails are not being sent out and there is no way to debug sendgrid in nodejs ?

Comment: Found the error "Substitutions may not be used with dynamic templating"

Comment: There's an update in there docs. Try using .`dynamic_template_data` instead of `substitutions` https://github.com/sendgrid/sendgrid-nodejs/issues/703

Comment: for adding html content through dynamic_template_data, you have to include variable name in sendgrid template as {{{varible_name}}} instead of {{varible_name}}.  please refer https://github.com/sendgrid/sendgrid-csharp/issues/738

Answer (score 0):

You can do it with Notifire

```
npm install @notifire/core @notifire/sendgrid
```

And then just

```
import { Notifire, ChannelTypeEnum } from '@notifire/core';
import { SendgridEmailProvider } from '@notifire/sendgrid';

const notifire = new Notifire();

await notifire.registerProvider(
  new SendgridEmailProvider({
    apiKey: process.env.SENDGRID_API_KEY,
    from: 'sender@mail.com'
  })
);

const passwordResetTemplate = await notifire.registerTemplate({
  id: 'password-reset',
  messages: [
    {
      subject: `You password reset request`,
      // Or for translation or custom logic you can use function syntax
      // subject: (payload: ITriggerPayload) => getTranslation('resetPasswordSubject', payload.language),
      channel: ChannelTypeEnum.EMAIL,
      template: `
          Hi {{firstName}}!
          
          To reset your password click <a href="{{resetLink}}">here.</a>
          
          {{#if organization}}
            <img src="{{organization.logo}}" />
          {{/if}}
      `
    },
  ]
});

await notifire.trigger('<REPLACE_WITH_EVENT_NAME>', {
  $user_id: "<USER IDENTIFIER>",
  $email: "test@email.com",
  firstName: "John",
  lastName: "Doe",
  language: "en",
  organization: {
    logo: 'https://evilcorp.com/logo.png'
  }
});
```